# Meu POST não está enviando nada

Tags: php, html, post

NO HTML:

```
    <form method="post"  action="../../../consulta.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="login" id="flogin" 
           placeholder="Insira o seu Login">
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="mandar" class="btn btn-success btn- 
           block" onclick="" value="Entrar">
   </form>
```

NO PHP

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        if (!empty($_POST['login'])) {
          $filtro = $_POST['login'];

          // aqui caso tudo estiver certo
         } else {
          echo "Por favor, preencha o seu login";
         }

    } else {
       echo "O campo 'login' não existe na variável $_POST";
    }

} else {

  echo "Não houve submit no formulário";

}
```

Ele cai no ultimo `echo` onde diz que não houve submit no form, onde foi que eu errei? Já tentei de tudo, e não da certo, não me mostra nada mesmo quando eu digito um valor, me ajudem. Está tudo dentro da tag body e html, o erro por algum motivo está ai

Comment: Pressione `F12` e verifique na aba *Network* a requisição POST; Verifique se algum conteúdo chega usando `var_dump(fgets(STDIN));`

Comment: Está me retornando Bool(false), e não tem nada no f12(Network)

Comment: Você poderia colocar mais uma parte do html? Eu testei seu código aqui e funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: É só isso mesmo, acho que terei que ficar mais um tempinho aqui vendo onde está o erro

Comment: Você está utilizando *JavaScript* para enviar o POST?

Comment: Form do html mesmo, esse mesmo form

Comment: vc está usando servidor local? Qual?

Comment: Acho que já encontrei o erro, tem nada a ver com os códigos que eu coloquei aqui, o erro em si era causado por um if que não achei que tinha relação com o problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem umas aberturas/fechamentos de `if` errado no seu código.

Dessa forma fica correto:

```
<?php 
if (!empty($_POST)) {

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {

        if (!empty($_POST['login'])) {
            $filtro = $_POST['login'];
            echo "ok";
            // aqui caso tudo estiver certo
        } else {
            echo "Por favor, preencha o seu login";
        }
    }
} else {

    echo "Não houve submit no formulário";

}
?>
```

Comment: Já corrigi, o problema ainda persiste, não consigo ver problemas com o formulário no html.

Comment: Gera algum erro? Ou simplesmente cai no `echo "Não houve submit...`?

Comment: Só cai no "Não houve submit"

Comment: Isso que não da pra entender, esta tudo certo e não envia nada pelo POST

Comment: dê um var_dump($_POST) e veja o que está chegando lá.

Comment: Verifique a action tente mudar pra qual arquivo está mandando e veja o que chega

Comment: Esta indo exatamente para o consulta.php que está 3 niveis acima ;/